# Setting mapreduce.job.jar with a jar in path containing space

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to write a mapreduce program and one of the step is set mapreduce.job.jar with a file. It the file is in a path that doesn't contain space, the program works fine. But the path contains space, the path is encoded, and I will get an no jar found error.

Say the job jar is under /home/myname/workspace/myMapReduce.jar
When I set mapreduce.job.jar with this path, it's fine.

```
Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();       
conf.set("mapreduce.job.jar", file.toURI().toURL().toString());
```

But if the path is /home/my name/workspace/myMapReduce.jar ( a space between 'my' and 'name'), the

```
file.toURI().toURL().toString()
```

encode the path into /home/my%20name/workspace/myMapReduce.jar, and this fails the mapreduce program because there is no such a jar under this directory.

So is there a way to set mapreduce jar in path containing space? Or else, how can I set mapreduce.job.jar other than using file.toURI().toURL().toString()?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping the space character with '\'?

In your example:
 /home/my\ name/workspace/myMapReduce.jar

Comment: I'm not hard coding the path, I use file.toURI().toURL().toString(). To escape, how can I convert a file into a valid name? Specifically, which method(s) to call?

Comment: What does the file instance contain exactly? How is it created?

Comment: file points the myMapReduce.jar. File file = new File("/home/my name/workspace/myMapReduce.jar");

Comment: Anyway: I wouldn't use the toURL method in this case since the spaces will be replaced by "%20".

Comment: That's my question, what do you use as alternative to toURL?

Comment: Did you try: file.toPath.toString()   ?

Comment: Just to understand better, which is the purpose of setting such a parameter in the conf? I mean, are you going to use such a parameter latter, for any reason, in the mapper or the reducer? If not, maybe you can try to set the jar in the job object by using the setJarByClass(yourClass.class) method.